# Join 2 tables from different databases

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, adodb

Is it possible joining two tables from different databases in php using MSSQL server and ADODB connections?

```
/*Connect DB1*/
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$conn->open("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=SRV;UID=user;PWD=pwd;DATABASE=DB1;");

/*Connect DB1*/
$conn2 = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$conn2->open("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=SRV;UID=user;PWD=pwd;DATABASE=DB2;");
```

I need to perform a JOIN query on these two databases, something like this:

```
select col from DB1.table1 JOIN DB2.table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need 2 connections to do that, you can do this just with one connection since connection user has access to both databases

You just need to put database name before table name

[database_name].[dbo].[table_name]

Here is how you could do that from your given example:

```
SELECT a.col FROM [DB1].[dbo].[table1] a
INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[table] b ON a.col = b.col
```

Comment: I tried your solutions and it raise an exception: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message ... Invalid object name 'db.dbo.table1'

Comment: Do you really have a database named "db" or a table named "table1" on this database? That's what error is saying. In your given connection strings, you just have "db1" and "db2" not "db"

Comment: Obviously I changed these values. OK... I was wrong with the parameters.. Now it works well. Thank you guy!